# How to check if JQuery libraries (and files with own code) are included correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frameworks

I have a JavaScript file with code that uses JQuery libraries. How can I verify that the file, as well as the JQuery libraries, are included correctly?

(Sorry if this is a kind of a stupid question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking it with window.jQuery onload windows

```js
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        alert("JQuery librairy loaded successfully");
    } else {
        alert("JQuery is not loaded");
    }
```

I believe you can even write :

```js
    if (jQuery) {  
        alert("JQuery librairy loaded successfully");
    } else {
        alert("JQuery is not loaded");
    }
```